# In MSQL Workbench, PHP can be scripted together with MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

Does MYSQL WORKBENCH have any feature to accommodate PHP scripting within MYSQL scripts and edit PHP scripts as it does MYSQL script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but PhpMyAdmin's designer does.

Comment: thanks, I tried to download PhpMyAdmin and use it and failed.  Will try some other time.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. MySQL Workbench is a Database administrative tool, not a webdev GUI.

Comment: thanks for fast response.  Sad that feature is not available.